# How do I get the labels from a post

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am new to wordpress and in the post admin section there is a place on the right that is clearly called `labels`.  I need to be able to access these `labels` and display them on the post when it is rendered.

I did some research and i found this code below, it seems to make sense but does not do what I need it too.

```
<?php   
    $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post) );  
    echo $post_type->label;
 ?>
```

I created 2 labels called `test` and `test2` and assigned them to the post.  When this code executes it echo's `posts`. There is a label property in the `post_type` object but I do not believe that it is the one I am looking for.

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the section?

Comment: @kraftner updated

Comment: Are you using a plugin to add labels functionality?

Comment: `labels` appears to be a taxonomy.

Comment: @MaxYudin no, but thank you just found it hard coded in the functions.php +1 for debugging assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, Labels appears to be a taxonomy, not a post type (which is why your code snippet didn't work. Probably the easiest way to get to do this is using `get_the_term_list()` like so:

```
echo get_the_term_list( get_the_id(), 'labels', '', ', ', '' );
```

That snippet assumes two things:

1. That it's used in the loop.
2. That "labels" is the correct taxonomy name. You should go to Posts > Labels and look for `taxonomy=___________` in the admin page's URL to figure out the correct taxonomy name for use above.

If you need a list of post terms to work with in PHP, use `get_the_terms()` instead.

p.s. It's worth noting that "Labels" is not a core WordPress taxonomy so it must be registered by a theme, plugin, or other custom piece of code that may provide alternate ways of displaying the labels on the front end.